# NoSQL database service for storing hundreds of gigabytes?

Tags: database, azure, amazon-web-services, storage, google-cloud-platform

I'm building an app, that will need to store approx 100-200GB of JSON data per month with ~20.000 write operations per minute.
Is there any service that won't require millions of dollars to store this data?

Comment: Not unless you build one yourself.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an infrastructure cost model question, not a programming question.

Comment: Further: You've included several cloud providers here in your question tags. Asking for tool recommendations (and in this case, I'm including vendor recommendations) is off-topic on StackOverflow (and a "which cloud do I choose" question is going to get you nothing but opinions). Each provider clearly lists their service pricing for their available database services. Plus, you can price out VMs+attached storage for self-hosted database services.

Comment: @durbnpoisn - That's simply not true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody. After all, I decided to go with Azure Table Storage.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use Azure's HDInsight. You'd pay for the HDInsight servers in addition to the storage of the data. Of course your costs will keep climbing as you add more and more data, so some form of archive would make sense. How long do you have to keep data easily available?

[HDInsight Pricing](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/hdinsight/)
[Storage Pricing](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/storage/)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be overestimating your data growth. I would start with either AWS or Azure and build my own datacenter if volume goes near the level you are talking about. Yes this involves some migration later on but its always good to grow by observation.

Comment: The estimation of someone's data growth is irrelevant in this context. Also, suggesting someone build their own data center? I don't understand that suggestion at all.